# Or Tools OPTIMAL solution violates constraint

Tags: mathematical-optimization, or-tools

I was testing a MILP model recently (probably this model needs some corrections, maybe some constraints are in conflict with each other) and I don't understand why a solution with status OPTIMAL violates the constraints after an additional check. I tried reducing the coefficients to minimize the error (infinity from 10000 to 1000 in the example) but the result is the same. How do you explain this behavior?

Minimal example:
https://replit.com/@Pietro234432324/Or-tools-Example

Comment: can you try different solvers ?

Comment: I also tried with "GLOP_LINEAR_PROGRAMMING"

Comment: No, glop is a simplex, not a MIP solver. SCIP? CP-SAT?

Comment: Okay I tried replacing it with `pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SAT')` but still the result is the same. I noticed that the model works until constraint number 9 is added

Answer (score 1):

```
b[i] * infinity
```

makes no sense for a solver. Just set b to 0 and remove it from the equation.
Do not expect any valid answer with these kind of modeling.

Furthermore, the bound <= expr <= bound is silently failing.
Replace the code by:

```
    # 8
    solver.Add(m[i] - b[i] * infinity <= t[i + 1] - r[i] - t[i])
    solver.Add(t[i + 1] - r[i] - t[i] <= M[i] + b[i] * infinity)
    # 9
    solver.Add(m[i] + (b[i] - 1) * infinity <= T + t[i + 1] - r[i] - t[i])
    solver.Add(T + t[i + 1] - r[i] - t[i] <= M[i] + (1 - b[i]) * infinity)
```

And change infinity by a more sensible constant (1e6 maybe) and everything works.

As said in your previous post, all bounds/constants must be reasonable, finite, non nans, with a limited log range (log10(max constant) - log10(min constant) < 10.

Comment: The model is from a paper and infinity represent a large number, for example I picked 10000. The smallest numbers in the model are single or double digit integers.

Comment: But you have both `inf` and `infinity` in your code.

Comment: It is the name of the variable taken from the paper. It's not the same as `math.inf`